# 16.04 with 4.15.0-36-generic kernel: system freezes with several worker threads blocked/hanging in BTRFS module

Tags: kernel, mount, filesystem, btrfs

We are Ubuntu shop running Xenial (16.04) with Linux kernel 4.15.0-36-generic. We recently migrated our application code from Ubuntu 14.04/linux kernel 4.4.0-23. We are experiencing some system hang issues (described below) with 16.04 environment, that we did not encounter with 14.04 and the 4.4 kernel.

Our secondary storage (256GB Micron SSD) is mounted on /dev/sdb with BTRFS filesystem. We are experiencing a system hang during large file copy/modify operations with following messages like this on the system console tty:

```
> [147778.018904] INFO: task btrfs-transacti:440 blocked for more than
> 120 seconds. [147778.026992]       Tainted: P           OE   
> 4.15.0-36-generic #1 [147778.033914] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
> [147778.042918] INFO: task auditd:1138 blocked for more than 120
> seconds. [147778.050218]       Tainted: P           OE   
> 4.15.0-36-generic #1 [147778.057116] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
> [147778.066125] INFO: task cron:24933 blocked for more than 120
> seconds. [147778.073317]       Tainted: P           OE   
> 4.15.0-36-generic #1 [147778.080225] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
> [147778.089664] INFO: task cron:24934 blocked for more than 120
> seconds. [147778.096866]       Tainted: P           OE   
> 4.15.0-36-generic #1 [147778.103764] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
> [147778.113159] INFO: task cron:24935 blocked for more than 120
> seconds. [147778.120360]       Tainted: P           OE   
> 4.15.0-36-generic #1 [147778.127267] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
> [147898.850483] INFO: task btrfs-transacti:440 blocked for more than
> 120 seconds. [147898.858569]       Tainted: P           OE   
> 4.15.0-36-generic #1 [147898.865490] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

This happens sometimes during shutdown (reboot) or during system bringup. We do have several file operations going on in background during these times. We were able to collect "dmesg" output from an ssh session that was still alive:

```
    [ 1034.371130] perf: interrupt took too long (14517 > 14503), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 13750
[ 1157.254266] BTRFS info (device sdb3): disk space caching is enabled
[ 1157.290278] BTRFS info (device sdb3): disk space caching is enabled
[ 1157.312982] BTRFS info (device sdb3): disk space caching is enabled
[ 1157.332657] BTRFS info (device sdb3): disk space caching is enabled
[ 1248.012861] ata1.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[ 1248.020748]  sda: sda1
                sda1: <solaris: [s0] sda5 [s2] sda6 [s8] sda7 >
[ 1257.996027] BTRFS info (device sdb3): qgroup scan completed (inconsistency flag cleared)
[ 1451.046237] INFO: task kworker/u24:0:5 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1451.054217]       Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-36-generic #1
[ 1451.061152] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1451.069963] kworker/u24:0   D    0     5      2 0x80000000
[ 1451.070199] Workqueue: btrfs-endio-write btrfs_endio_write_helper [btrfs]
[ 1451.070257] Call Trace:
[ 1451.070312]  __schedule+0x3d6/0x8b0
[ 1451.070332]  ? blk_rq_map_sg+0x13c/0x550
[ 1451.070336]  schedule+0x36/0x80
[ 1451.070366]  btrfs_tree_lock+0xef/0x210 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070381]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[ 1451.070400]  btrfs_lock_root_node+0x34/0x50 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070417]  btrfs_search_slot+0x914/0x9d0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070421]  ? update_load_avg+0x5e0/0x700
[ 1451.070442]  btrfs_lookup_file_extent+0x49/0x60 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070465]  __btrfs_drop_extents+0x19e/0xe60 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070488]  ? __set_extent_bit+0x466/0x5a0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070510]  ? __set_extent_bit+0x466/0x5a0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070513]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[ 1451.070515]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[ 1451.070535]  insert_reserved_file_extent.constprop.68+0x90/0x2d0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070557]  ? start_transaction+0x9b/0x440 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070578]  btrfs_finish_ordered_io+0x300/0x720 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070601]  ? end_compressed_bio_write+0x102/0x140 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070622]  finish_ordered_fn+0x15/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070644]  normal_work_helper+0xcb/0x320 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070667]  btrfs_endio_write_helper+0x12/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 1451.070672]  process_one_work+0x14d/0x410
[ 1451.070675]  worker_thread+0x4b/0x460
[ 1451.070679]  kthread+0x105/0x140
[ 1451.070680]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
[ 1451.070683]  ? kthread_destroy_worker+0x50/0x50
[ 1451.070686]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[ 1451.070733] INFO: task kworker/u24:1:101 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1451.078559]       Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-36-generic #1
[ 1451.085426] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1451.094228] kworker/u24:1   D    0   101      2 0x80000000
[ 1451.094275] Workqueue: btrfs-endio-write btrfs_endio_write_helper [btrfs]
[ 1451.094278] Call Trace:
[ 1451.094282]  __schedule+0x3d6/0x8b0
[ 1451.094285]  schedule+0x36/0x80
[ 1451.094307]  btrfs_tree_lock+0xef/0x210 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094310]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[ 1451.094327]  btrfs_lock_root_node+0x34/0x50 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094343]  btrfs_search_slot+0x914/0x9d0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094363]  btrfs_lookup_file_extent+0x49/0x60 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094384]  __btrfs_drop_extents+0x19e/0xe60 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094407]  ? __set_extent_bit+0x466/0x5a0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094428]  ? __set_extent_bit+0x466/0x5a0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094431]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[ 1451.094434]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[ 1451.094455]  insert_reserved_file_extent.constprop.68+0x90/0x2d0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094475]  ? start_transaction+0x9b/0x440 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094495]  btrfs_finish_ordered_io+0x300/0x720 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094499]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[ 1451.094503]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
[ 1451.094505]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
[ 1451.094524]  finish_ordered_fn+0x15/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094546]  normal_work_helper+0xcb/0x320 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094569]  btrfs_endio_write_helper+0x12/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 1451.094571]  process_one_work+0x14d/0x410
[ 1451.094575]  worker_thread+0x4b/0x460
[ 1451.094578]  kthread+0x105/0x140
[ 1451.094580]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
[ 1451.094582]  ? kthread_destroy_worker+0x50/0x50
[ 1451.094585]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[ 1451.094603] INFO: task kworker/u24:2:271 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1451.102453]       Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-36-generic #1
[ 1451.109330] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1451.118138] kworker/u24:2   D    0   271      2 0x80000000
[ 1451.118165] Workqueue: btrfs-endio-write btrfs_endio_write_helper [btrfs]
[ 1451.118173] Call Trace:
[ 1451.118180]  __schedule+0x3d6/0x8b0
[ 1451.118183]  schedule+0x36/0x80
[ 1451.118205]  btrfs_tree_lock+0xef/0x210 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118215]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
[ 1451.118231]  btrfs_lock_root_node+0x34/0x50 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118252]  btrfs_search_slot+0x914/0x9d0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118273]  btrfs_lookup_file_extent+0x49/0x60 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118296]  __btrfs_drop_extents+0x19e/0xe60 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118319]  ? __set_extent_bit+0x466/0x5a0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118342]  ? __set_extent_bit+0x466/0x5a0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118346]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[ 1451.118368]  insert_reserved_file_extent.constprop.68+0x90/0x2d0 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118389]  ? start_transaction+0x9b/0x440 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118412]  btrfs_finish_ordered_io+0x300/0x720 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118435]  finish_ordered_fn+0x15/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118459]  normal_work_helper+0xcb/0x320 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118484]  btrfs_endio_write_helper+0x12/0x20 [btrfs]
[ 1451.118487]  process_one_work+0x14d/0x410
[ 1451.118490]  worker_thread+0x4b/0x460
[ 1451.118493]  kthread+0x105/0x140
[ 1451.118495]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
[ 1451.118498]  ? kthread_destroy_worker+0x50/0x50
[ 1451.118501]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
```

The following is our /etc/fstab entries that shows the various BTRFS mount options that we have already tried one at a time:

```
UUID=3a899529-c5e4-42ae-a4ea-7b645f9bcb59 /               btrfs defaults,autodefrag,thread_pool=4,compress=lzo,noatime,subvol=@/netvisor-1 0       1
UUID=3a899529-c5e4-42ae-a4ea-7b645f9bcb59 /home           btrfs defaults,autodefrag,thread_pool=4,compress=lzo,noatime,subvol=@home 0       2
UUID=3a899529-c5e4-42ae-a4ea-7b645f9bcb59 /var/nvOS/log   btrfs defaults,autodefrag,thread_pool=4,compress=lzo,noatime,subvol=@var_nvOS_log 0       2
UUID=3a899529-c5e4-42ae-a4ea-7b645f9bcb59 /.rootbe btrfs defaults,autodefrag,thread_pool=4,compress=lzo,noatime,subvol=@ 0 1
```

Does this indicate that we are hitting some known issues with BTRFS filesystem deadlock that may have been fixed in later kernel versions? If so, how should we go about obtaining those fixes in our current kernel? Upgrading the kernel is not an option for us at this time. Are there any other BTRFS mount options or any other system tunable parameters we could try to circumvent this hang issues.
Thanks in advance.